# Kubernetes LoadBalancer with inner nginx SSL redirect

Tags: ssl, kubernetes

I'm kind of here looking for clarification as can't seem to find it online.

I have a Dockerimage that bundles PHP-FPM/nginx.

When I hit port 80, it redirects to 443 with my certificates - Works perfectly and as intended.

I've recently been looking into Kubernetes and understand the basic concepts.

Im trying to get it up and running in Minikube but can't seem to get the SSL redirect working.

Is this posible?

Do I need to only use port 80 in my app and use SSL at ingress level?

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: laravel-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  minReadySeconds: 10
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
      maxSurge: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: laravel-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: laravel-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: image/laravel-app:latest
          name: laravel-app
          ports:
            - name: 'http'
              containerPort: 80
            - name: 'https'
              containerPort: 443
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: laravel-config
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: laravel-ingress
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - host: laravel.localhost
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: laravel-app-service
              servicePort: 80
    - host: laravel.localhost
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: laravel-app-service
              servicePort: 443
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: laravel-app-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: laravel-app
  ports:
    - port: 80
      name: 'http'
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30080
    - port: 443
      name: 'https'
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 443
      nodePort: 30443
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: laravel-config
  labels:
    name: laravel-config
data:
  APP_ENV: "dev"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#server-side-https-enforcement-through-redirect) annotation:

> When using SSL offloading outside of cluster (e.g. AWS ELB) it may be
>   useful to enforce a redirect to HTTPS even when there is no TLS
>   certificate is available. This can be achieved by using the
>   `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"` annotation in
>   the particular resource.